# Make login information secure in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In my program, I have a simple login prompt so that only certain users may enter a program, as well as make the program function differently depending on the user.  What I would like to do is have the information for the user login information (username, password, etc.) securely stored without going through an online database.  I know that using a text file to store this information is a very bad idea, and I'm sure there is an easier way to do this than to make an array of this login information internally inside my program.  Could you all give me some suggestions of a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashes are what you need. Paste a hash-making function into your code, `MD5` functions are available online for all major platforms. Then store your pairs of hashes in your config file. Devise a clever way to combine a password with your admittance options into another hash so that the file is edit-proof. This way, you can distribute the account configuration and if you don't make a trivial cryptographic mistake, it will work just as you want.
Example of the config file line (hashes truncated to 6 chars for clarity):

`1a2b3c print;search;evaluate 4d5e6f`

Here, 1a2b3c is obtained as `MD5(username.Text+verysecret)`, the verbs are the account's rights and 4d5e6f is obtained as `MD5(line[1]+verysecret+password.Text)` where line[1] is the split result of the config line where the verbs are stored and the rest is the user's password.

Note how the password gets automatically salted by the verbs and how the verbs are protected against editing because that would invalidate the password hash. The verysecret constant is something hidden in your executable code that will prevent anybody from computing the hashes and unlocking the program.

Hashing is not an asymmetric cipher or key pair; a motivated attacker can crack your program to bypass protection altogether anyway, so going to further lengths is useless.

If you are cheap to find an asymmetric scheme, but cunning enough, you can change a few initialization constants in that MD5 function. This will make the cracking of your code harder, especially against the making of a counterfeit account file.

EDIT: When authenticating, don't just `if(hashfromconfig == computedhash)...` Script kiddies know how to hook into the string comparison function. Write `if(MD5(hashfromconfig) == MD5(computedhash))...` instead... Then the string comparison will work just as before, only it will not see your precious key hash that goes into a wannabe-counterfeit file. Ideally, have several versions of the MD5 function scattered across your code and named differently. Use `if(foo(hashfromconfig) == bar(computedhash))...` for a nice effect.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that using a server will make this process more secure.  However, since this will only be installed on a few machines (which will not have an internet connection), I will take my chances and use hashes for securely storing this login information. I've heard that MD5 is more vulnerable, so I might try to use a SDA hash

Comment: Don't be afraid to use MD5; for this application, MD5 won't be vulnerable at all. In other words, you don't put vault door on a house that has a plain glass window right next to it. Any hash function will be adequate for your needs. The vulnerability of MD5 is such that both messages are crafted to meet in the middle, leveraging the "birthday paradox" to reduce the complexity by a square root. There is no chance anybody would break into your app by cracking the hash. Regular code cracking is the glass window of the parable.

Answer (score 0):

"without going through an online database." - do you mean on the client side?

"securely stored" and "client side" are pretty much mutually exclusive terms in this scenario.

There is absolutely no way to securely store data without touching online (server-side) source of some kind. If you are touching server-side source, it might as well be a DB.

Comment: What if this program will not have many clients? In other words, the program I will be creating will only be installed on one or two machines.  Also, I am not certain that these machines will always have an internet connection.

Comment: If the PC doesn't have access to Inet, then you can use hashing as Zdenek suggested (although I didn't understand half of what he was describing... must be my lack of knowledge on the matter). To further increase security and reliability, you can create a security-fob (a simple USB flash card) that contains the salt for the hashing function. This way, the user must insert the flash card into the PC before logging in. Even if someone knows the user/pass combo, it won't work without the flashcard. I've seen some tricky flash cards - you couldn't browse it to steal the salt file.

Comment: @Gorge Thanks for that advice.  The USB idea is pretty nifty.  I'll see if I can implement that as well